# How to calculate WAPE for given dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, forecasting

I want to know to how to calculate WAPE value if we have the dataframe in the below format.
I am using python. I need it for evaluating Forecasting.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_forecasting), the WAPE (Weighted Absolute Percent Error) can be calculated by

> dividing the sum of the absolute deviations by the total sales of all products.

In pandas, you can do that by using the `-` operator, which will work element-wise between series, combined with the [`abs()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) and [`sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) methods for series (and regular float division):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': [23, 32, 44, 37, 48, 42, 39],
                   'Forecasted': [25, 30, 41, 34, 45, 47, 40]})

wape = (df.Actual - df.Forecasted).abs().sum() / df.Actual.sum()
print(wape)
```

```
0.07169811320754717
```